# XML Validation against XSD using Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have requirement, to validate the XML against the XSD.

I need the tag name where the problem is. The below URL code is good, it validates the contents and throws exception, but it does not give the element name which is having problem. Is there a way to get the element name ?

http://shyamalmadura.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/how-to-validate-xml-file-againt-xsd/

Comment: I usually use SAXParserFactory API, but it says there is an error too, and doesn't say exactly where's the problem. I will be looking this topic for a nice answer

Comment: The validation error does say the offending element, line and column, what else do you need?

Comment: Reason : cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'hub:equipment' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.example.com/hub/":component, "http://www.example.com/hub/":analysis}' is expected.
Line Number : 180
Column Number : 26

Comment: I need the element name and path of the element. That will help in tracking down the exact location.

Comment: Sorry, I jsut read the example again. Somehow, when I am validating against my XSD, the element name is not being retreived